# Read Contacts in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to read all Names from the AdressBook in the Smartphone.
I've tested following code, but it won't work:

```
CrossContacts.Current.PreferContactAggregation = false;
var hasPermission = CrossContacts.Current.RequestPermission().Result;

if (hasPermission)
{
   Contacts = CrossContacts.Current.Contacts.Select(
      contact => contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName);
}
```

Also Visual Studio throws an exception like following:

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type
>   'Plugin.Contacts.ProjectionReader`1[System.String]' cannot be used for
>   return type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[System.String]'

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return all the contacts with the first/last name concatenated together, return them to a `List<string>` instead of a `List<Contact>`:

```
List<string> nameList = CrossContacts.Current.Contacts.Select(contact => contact.FirstName + " " + contact.LastName).ToList();
```

If you are trying to return the whole `Contact` record to a List:

```
List<Contact> contacts = CrossContacts.Current.Contacts.ToList();
```

*Note: Be aware that with unified contacts, a user can have thousands of contacts that could be returned since you are applying no filtering.*

Comment: Thank, you for the answer. Not the LINQ Statements are the problems. The exception is the problem! The Contacts Property has the type IEnumerable<string>. So, it should work.

Comment: @NiklasRaab Then what is the variable `Contacts` in your code defined as?

Comment: @NiklasRaab What is the "type" of `Contacts`

Comment: IEnumerable<string> but i think it's an bug. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is currently a bug in the Xamarin Plugin: 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/issues/272